# Changing which side of the screen the compiler is on

Tags: overleaf

on Overleaf, does anyone know if it is possible to change on what side of the screen the compiler is on vs the pdf viewer?

Comment: This is not really a LaTeX question, might be better to write to Overleaf support directly

Comment: Yes - please contact Overleaf support with any questions that are about Overleaf (support@overleaf.com). Just to answer the question here, currently you cannot switch the position of the compiler and pdf viewer (I'm a member of the Overleaf support team).